# Mysql find difference between current and last hour and print with current hour row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, hour

Need to get the difference for two values between current hour and last hour as mentioned below.

As first step i tried finding the current hour values but not sure how to subtract the second last hour value from it and display along with current hour row

```
    select mmeName,startDate,max(startTime),endDate,max(endTime),c_ratio,set_time

    from attach 

    where type='INIT' and endDate=Date(now())

    group by mmeName
```

My existing table format and the required output is captured in the attached image.

any help/suggestion would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What is last_diff and last_diff_2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql retrieve difference between current and last hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592983/mysql-retrieve-difference-between-current-and-last-hour)

Comment: last hr diff is col-F (c_ratio of current_hour - last_hour) and similarly last hr diff2 is Col-G(set_time)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an auto-increment id in your table, try this query:

```
SELECT a1.mmeName, a1.c_ratio, a1.set_time, a0.c_ratio - a1.c_ratio AS last_hr, a0.set_time - a1.set_time AS last_hr_2
FROM attach a1
JOIN attach a0 ON a0.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM attach WHERE id < a1.id AND mmeName = a1.mmeName)
```

In this query, `a1` refers to the current row, while `a0` refers to the previous row with the same `mmeName`. Then, you can build fields like `last_hr` like this: `a0.c_ratio - a1.c_ratio`.

If you only need one row for each `mmeName`, you will have to sum differences, and `GROUP BY mmeName`.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have an auto-increment id in my table :(

Comment: Then, how could you sort rows? What's your primary key?

Comment: Im a newbie to mysql. Please bear with me! Im going to modify my table to include a new column `id` as primary key!

Comment: Actually this query works partially...in the sense it selects the latest date row(i.e current date) but not selecting the latest hour(current time) for each mmeName


`SELECT a1.id, a1.mmeName, a1.startDate, a1.startTime, a1.c_ratio, a1.set_time, truncate(a0.c_ratio - a1.c_ratio,2) AS last_hr, truncate(a0.set_time - a1.set_time,2) AS last_hr_2
FROM attach a1
JOIN attach a0 ON a0.id= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM attach WHERE id < a1.id  AND mmeName = a1.mmeName) where a1.startDate=curDate() group by mmeName`

14062 Akron1 2013-11-06 00:00:00 85.07 625.88 -85.06 -625.88